# While working with reactjs Routes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When trying to run Switch in react js, it just gives me a blank screen with no output. I checked online and the solution that i found was to replace Switch with Routes which also seems to give no output.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Homepage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <p>This is the Homepage</p>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/join" component={<RoomJoinPage />} />
          <Route path="/create" component={<CreateRoomPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting a paragraph tag saying "This is the homepage" but receiving a blank screen instead

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Homepage from "./Homepage";


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Homepage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code inside a codepen, nothing appear. I then checked an [example on how to use react-router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/src/App.tsx). I simply fixed the problem changing

```
<Route path="/join" component={<RoomJoinPage />} />
```

to

```
<Route path="/join" element={<RoomJoinPage />} />
```

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-silence-d120ey?file=/src/App.js).

You can check out the documentation of react router [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route).

When running the codepen, I found the following error : "[p] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>". Try to place your p inside the props

```
element={<p>This is the HomePage</p>}
```

Other then that, I can't see anything else wrong. But it's weird that the app can run with an error.

I hope this helps, feel free to respond if this doesn't solved your issue.

Comment: Hey, i tried running this on my local machine and it does not seem to work still

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom are you using ?

Comment: router-dom = 6.8.2

Comment: I updated my codepen https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-silence-d120ey?file=/src/Homepage.js , the only left error that I can see, it's the first route. As I try to run your code in my codepen, It said : "[p] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>". Try to place your <p> inside the props element={<p>This is the HomePage</p>}. Other then that, I can't see anything else wrong. But it's weird that the app can run with an error.

Comment: Yes thank you that seems to be have been the problem